# Salary and taxes for first time workers

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, salary, payment

I'm really hoping you could help me understand the taxes and what will be my net salary. I've started to work for the first time in the UK on May the 9th 2016. My income will be 26000/year (gross). I've have checked many UK calculator and they all say I will get  £1,737.27 net, however I have been reading that if it's the first time you work in the UK you don't pay taxes for the first months. Is that correct? I received my payslip and it's the most strange thing I've seen and they combine May & June as apparently didn't have the time to get me a code for May (?). This is a very small office, I have asked my colleagues and no one knows and the account never got back to me. Could you please be so kind to help me figuring out how much will I take home every month?

Thank you in advance for your help.

M.

Comment: I don't know where you got the idea that "if it's the first time you work in the UK you don't pay taxes for the first months" its not true.